# dummy "it" + was/were?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, dummy-pronouns

What is correct in the following sentence:

> It **was**/**were** our musical expeditions to Berlin that encouraged us to do that.

I think the plural of "expeditions" indicates "were" but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: In a cleft construction like this, the dummy pronoun "it" is the subject. But dummy "it" has only singular form, it has no plural, so even though the complement of "be" is the plural "our musical expeditions", the subject has to be "it", and the verb also has to be singular.

Answer (score 2):

As "it" is singular, "was" sounds most natural to me

"It was my favourite shop"

"They were my favourite sweets"