# is it "was" or "were"

Tags: american-english

I'm writing a book and I don't know how to write the first sentence.
Is it "It was my thoughts that began to drive me slightly mad." or "It were my thoughts that began to drive me slightly mad"

Comment: The dummy pronoun "it" takes singular agreement, so the singular "was" is correct.

Comment: You can't say 'it were'. Your thoughts were the cause (singular) of your madness.

Comment: It might be rather "odd" phrasing, but in principle, ***They were** my thoughts that began to drive me slightly mad* is at least syntactically valid.

Comment: If you really wanna go nuts with it "My thoughts were the ones that had begun to drive me slightly mad". This makes it sound like you and your thoughts are not entirely one, which might be stylistically kind of cool...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dummy "it" + was/were?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102109/dummy-it-was-were)